# WEKA Ham or Spam J48 is greyed out

Tags: weka

I have a problem. In Weka I want to use J48 algorithm but I cant use it for `(NUM) ham yes or no`
[image: Pic1]

J48 is greyed out (see Picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqQMK.png))

[image]

Can someone help me figure out why it's greyed out please?